# How can I make a button stay to the right no matter the screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this button made in js it has an image on top and a link, how can i make it so no matter any screen size it stays to the right, because i tried 100% 100vw but it made it to the right to much to the point you to scroll to the right in order to see it, i tried 86 for both it worked on my screen size but made it so you to scroll to the right in order to see it.

```css
  .set {
  background-color: black;
  .invisible {
    display: none
  }
}

button {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  /* put the height and width of your image here */
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  border: none;
  color: black position:relative;
}

button span {
  display: none;
}

.btn1 {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/RPZ82RK/DRAFT.jpg");
  margin-left: 80vw;
}

#test {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  padding: 0px;
}

h1 {
  background: #ee6c4d;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin: 50px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  -moz-background-inline-policy: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
}

.tablink {
  border-radius: 500px;
  background-color: #1a2858;
  padding-top: -10px;
  color: white;
  float: center;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 55.6px;
  height: 55.6px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1.5%;
  color: white;
  font-family: yaqout;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tablink:hover {
  background-color: #49e2f8;
}


/* Set default styles for tab content */

.tabcontent color: white;
display: none;
padding: 14px;
text-align: center;

}
.container {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
.center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.header {
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #489795;
  color: #1a2858;
  font-size: 70px;
  height: 10%;
  font-family: yaqout;
  font-weight: bold;
```

```html
<body style="background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/vhvmNbQ/1234.jpg.jpg');"></body>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="score" style="color: transparent; background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; cursor: default;position:absolute;">Click to see progress</button>
<button id="complete" style="color: transparent; background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; cursor: default;position:absolute;"></button>
</header>
<div class="header">
  <span> خواندن مرحله‌وار<span>
</div>
</body>
  <button class="tablink" id="c" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/ya/alif-ya.html'">ی</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="b" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/alif%20mat/alif-ya.html'">ه</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="a" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/wow/alif-ya.html'">و</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="29" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/nun/alif-ya.html'">ن</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="28" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/mem/alif-ya.html'">م</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="27" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/lam/alif-ya.html'">ل</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="26" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/gaf/alif-ya.html'">گ</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="25" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/kaf/alif-ya.html'">ک</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="24" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/gaf/alif-ya.html'">ق</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="23" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/fe/alif-ya.html'">ف</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="22" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/ghyn/alif-ya.html'">غ</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="21" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/ayn/alif-ya.html'">ع</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="20" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/zuy/alif-ya.html'">ظ</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="19" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/tuy/alif-ya.html'">ط</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="18" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/zad/alif-ya.html'">ض</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="17" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/sad/alif-ya.html'">ص</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="16" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/shen/alif-ya.html'">ش</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="15" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/sen/alif-ya.html'">س</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="14" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/ghe/alif-ya.html'">ژ</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="13" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/ze/alif-ya.html'">ز</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="12" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/re/alif-ya.html'">ر</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="11" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/zal/alif-ya.html'">ذ</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="10" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/dal/alif-ya.html'">د</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="9" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/khe/alif-ya.html'">خ</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="8" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/he/alif-ya.html'">ح</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="7" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/che/alif-ya.html'">چ</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="6" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/gym/alif-ya.html'">ج</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="5" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/the/alif-ya.html'">ث</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="4" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/te/alif-ya.html'">ت</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="3" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/pe/alif-ya.html'">پ</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="2" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/be/alif-ya.html'">ب</button>
  <button class="tablink" id="1" onclick="location.href='https://razkudak.000webhostapp.com/index.html/alif/alif-ya.html'">ا</button>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also the CSS to change the buttons things are on top of the CSS.

https://codepen.io/haroon1233212/pen/NWXQXRa

Comment: You have some malformed CSS at the beginning, and you have _many_ buttons in your demo. Which one are you talking about? Help us help you.

Comment: You also have multiple body elements, which is invalid. You must have one which contains all your content.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for keeping a button always in the same spot, absolute positioning should get the job done.

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: right 0 causes it to be a little bit to the left for some reason and when the page is smaller its a bit to much to the right so you have to scroll to the right in order to see the whole button

Comment: The one reason this might be happening is that the container overflows. I can't see the problem in the code example, so it's hard to tell really. Also make sure that the button has margin of zero px.